# Strange behavior of atomic_fetch_add regarding uint64

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include "atomic"

std::atomic<uint64_t>bid_index(0);
uint64_t generate_bid_key(){
  return std::atomic_fetch_add(&bid_index,1);
}
```

I have the following error:

```
No matching function for call to 'atomic_fetch_add' candidate template ignored: 
deduced conflicting types for parameter '_Tp' ('unsigned long long' vs. 'int') 
candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for 
parameter '_Tp' ('unsigned long long' vs. 'int') 
candidate template ignored: could not match 'type-parameter-0-0 *' against 
'unsigned long long' candidate template ignored: could not match 'type-parameter-0-0 *' 
against 'unsigned long long'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please check your code formatting and preferably post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please see the link in my previous comment. Either there is a bug in code you didn't post, or your compiler is non-conforming

Comment: Thanks and I have seen that. It is a compiler issue for me so I don't really know how much code I need to post. Basically I have a global variable and a function call on it. And the line return std::atomic_fetch_add(&bid_index,1); is throwing a compiler error

Comment: You need to post exactly what you are compiling to produce the error.  None of us can tell if there is a mistake in parts of your program that you didn't post . This is explained in the link.

Comment: Don’t paraphrase error messages. The error message said more than that, and the part you left out has useful information..

Comment: add #include <atomic>

Comment: Thanks I just include my "include" message here

Answer (score 1):

`std::atomic_fetch_add` deduce the templated type of the operand from the 2nd parameter `1` (which is an int) and it does not match the atomic's templated type (which is an `uint64_t`). Make it a `uint64_t` and it'll be accepted.

```
return std::atomic_fetch_add(&bid_index,1ULL);
```

or

```
return std::atomic_fetch_add(&bid_index,(uint64_t)1);
```

You can also use the more direct `fetch_add` method of the atomic class which is probably easier.